# Sharing object array between controllers while working with modal window in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to work with an object array which I am sharing among two controllers one of which is dealing with modal window.

Here is the js code.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .service('Faq', function ($http) {
    this.faqList = [];
    this.faqList = $http.get('/Json/faq.json');

    this.getFaqs = function ()
    {
        return this.faqList;
    }

    this.addfaq = function (obj) {
        this.faqList.push(obj);
    };


})
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope,$modal,Faq) {



    $scope.faqData = [];

    Faq.getFaqs().then(function (msg) {
        $scope.faqData = msg.data;

    });

    }

    $scope.show = function () {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "faqAddUpdate.html",
            controller: "faqctrl"
        });
    };


})
.controller('faqctrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, Faq) {
    $scope.question = '';
    $scope.id = '';
    $scope.answer = '';

    $scope.editFaq = function (id) {
        $scope.divFaq = true;
        $scope.faqs = [];
        Faq.getData().then(function (msg) {
            $scope.faqs = msg.data;
            var l = $scope.faqs.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if ($scope.faqs[i].id == id) {
                    $scope.question = $scope.faqs[i].question;
                    $scope.id = $scope.faqs[i].id;
                    $scope.answer = $scope.faqs[i].answer;

                }
            }
        });
    };


    $scope.AddUpdateFAQ = function () {
        var faq = {
            id: $scope.id,
            question: $scope.question,
            answer: $scope.answer
        };
        Faq.addfaq(faq);
        console.log(faq);
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.Cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };
});
```

but when I am submitting the data through the modal it says this.faqList.push is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your faqList variable is not an array.

You overide the first definition:

```
this.faqList = [];
```

With this:

```
this.faqList = $http.get('/Json/faq.json');
```

But $http.get returns a promise (see [doc](http://devdocs.io/angular~1.5/api/ng/service/$http#get)), not an array.

You should do something like this:

```
this.faqList = [];
$http.get('/Json/faq.json').then(function(result) {
  // process your results here
  this.faqList = result.data;
});
```

Comment: Although it is not showing the error which it was showing before when i am submitting the data but json data is not displaying now

Comment: What is in the 'result' variable in the promise callback ?

Comment: result variable would be having json object array

Comment: I think it's just an issue in the way you process the results of the promise. You have to adapt my code to your situation. Maybe it's not result.data, it depends on the structure of your data.

Comment: Yeah it worked . I just had to make some changes    `$http.get('/Json/faq.json').then(function (result) {
     result.data.forEach(function(item){
      self.addfaq(item)
    })
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Not tried, but `this` is within the function scope, so create a `_this` var first might help:

```
this.faqList = [];
this.faqList = $http.get('/Json/faq.json');
var _this = this;

this.getFaqs = function ()
{
    return _this.faqList;
}

this.addfaq = function (obj) {
    _this.faqList.push(obj);
};
```